# Class usage over multiple files .h .cpp main.cpp

Tags: c++, class, debugging, constructor, header

Attempting to make a Tamagotchi program but the compiler is throwing the undefined reference to 'Tamagotchi::age() error

This code would ideally return the age of the Tamagotchi which should be initialized to 0 at the start by the constructor of the class.

I obviously messed up somewhere but am not sure where, if anyone sees where and could help me understand that would be great!

Additionally if you see something that is poor coding practice, I'm new to this and am looking to improve so any assistance is welcome.

EDIT: whoops I forgot to copy and paste in the function definitions from within the class. They are there but I am still getting the compiler error.

```
//tamagotchi.cpp
#include "tamagotchi.h"
#include <string>


/* return of Tamagotchi information */
std::string Tamagotchi::name() {return myName;}
int Tamagotchi::age() {return myAge;}
int Tamagotchi::happiness() {return myHappiness;}
int Tamagotchi::hunger() {return myHunger;}
bool Tamagotchi::rIsSick() {return isSick;}
```

-

```
//tamagotchi.h
#ifndef TAMAGOTCHI_H
#define TAMAGOTCHI_H
#include <string>


class Tamagotchi
{
public:
        /* initialization of default for tamagotchi */
        Tamagotchi() 
        : myName ("Default"),
          myAge ( 0 ),
          myHappiness ( 0 ),
          myHunger ( 0 ),
          isSick ( false ) { }

/* returning tamagotchi variables */
        std::string name();
        int age();
        int happiness();
        int hunger();
        bool rIsSick();

private:
        std::string myName;
        int myAge;// defined from 0 - 50 based on hours
        int myHappiness;// defined from 0 - 10
        int myHunger; // defined from 0 - 10, greater is hungrier
        bool isSick;// defines whether or not the Tamagotchi is sick

};

#endif
```

-

```
//main.cpp
#include "tamagotchi.h" // defines tamagotchi class
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    Tamagotchi myTamagotchi;
    std::cout << myTamagotchi.age();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your accessor functions (or any member function for that matter) in the header file within the class declaration:

```
class Tamagotchi
{
public:
        /* initialization of default for tamagotchi */
        Tamagotchi() 
        : myName ("Default"),
          myAge ( 0 ),
          myHappiness ( 0 ),
          myHunger ( 0 ),
          isSick ( false ) { }
private:
        std::string myName;
        int myAge;// defined from 0 - 50 based on hours
        int myHappiness;// defined from 0 - 10
        int myHunger; // defined from 0 - 10, greater is hungrier
        bool isSick;// defines whether or not the Tamagotchi is sick
public:
    std::string name();
    int age();
    int happiness();
    int hunger();
    bool rIsSick();
};
```

Some tips: It's useful to declare member functions that don't modify the object's state as const, like so:

```
std::string name() const;
```

You also have to modify the definition in the cpp file accordingly:

```
std::string Tamagotchi::name() const {...}
```

I would also recommend that you return container objects such as std::string by const reference:

```
const std::string& name() const;
```

Again, you have to modify the definition in the cpp file:

```
const std::string& Tamagotchi::name() const { return myName; }
```

If you return it by value, as you have, you will always create a copy of the returned string, which may lead to reduced performance. Returning by const reference avoids this. This is only useful for containers and other large objects however. Simple things like primitive types (int, float, bool, etc.) and instances of small classes can be returned by value at almost no cost.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right... the class you've defined contains no function definitions, only a constructor and some private member variables. Throwing your methods in a .cpp file is not enough. If a method isn't in the class definition, then it doesn't exist as far as the rest of the application is concerned!

```
class Tamagotchi
{
public:
        /* initialization of default for tamagotchi */
        Tamagotchi() 
        : myName ("Default"),
          myAge ( 0 ),
          myHappiness ( 0 ),
          myHunger ( 0 ),
          isSick ( false ) { }

        std::string name();
        int age();
        int happiness();
        int hunger();
        bool rIsSick();

private:
        std::string myName;
        int myAge;// defined from 0 - 50 based on hours
        int myHappiness;// defined from 0 - 10
        int myHunger; // defined from 0 - 10, greater is hungrier
        bool isSick;// defines whether or not the Tamagotchi is sick
};
```